# Why does not it run the program in SWI-prolog

Tags: prolog

Why doesn't it launch even the most basic program, what am I doing wrong? (In the online version prolog - SWISH, everything works great).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOcHh.png)

Answer (score 1):

Prolog queries must end in a period:

```
?- task.
```